# Why didn't iptables reject the ping?

Tags: iptables, ping

I am an iptables newbie. While I had tried to learn as much as I can over the past few days, this problem beats me!

First of all, the environment is a VMWare (CentOS7) running on a Fedora 30 host. In the VM, there's a libvirt running OCP.

```
Local ethernet interface = ens33
libvirt bridge = virbr0
OCP bridge = crc


[danielyeap@localhost dnsmasq.d]$ ifconfig 
crc: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.130.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.130.255
        ether 52:54:00:fd:be:d0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:f4:2b:9f:8c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)

ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.125  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::a7ec:bc4d:3bae:8902  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:2d:54:83  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:c0:c1:92  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fcfd:fcff:fe07:2182  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:fd:fc:07:21:82  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)



[root@localhost docker]# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
crc             8000.525400fdbed0       yes             crc-nic
                                                        vnet0
docker0         8000.0242f42b9f8c       no
virbr0          8000.525400c0c192       yes             virbr0-nic
[root@localhost docker]#
```

For learning purposes, I decided to add ICMP reject on the first line of both the "FORWARD" and "INPUT" chains:

```
[root@localhost ~]# iptables -I FORWARD 1 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j REJECT
[root@localhost ~]# iptables -I INPUT 1 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j REJECT
[root@localhost ~]# 


[FORWARD CHAIN]
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 REJECT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
2     240K   70M DOCKER-USER  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
3     240K   70M DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
4        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
5        0     0 DOCKER     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere
6        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere
7        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere
8        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    virbr0  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
9        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 any     192.168.122.0/24     anywhere
10   0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  anywhere             anywhere
11   0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    virbr0  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
12       0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
13    125K   56M ACCEPT     all  --  any    crc     anywhere             192.168.130.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
14    116K   14M ACCEPT     all  --  crc    any     192.168.130.0/24     anywhere
15       0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  crc    crc     anywhere             anywhere
16     180 14160 REJECT     all  --  any    crc     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
17   0     0 REJECT     all  --  crc    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
18   0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
19   0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
20   0     0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
21   0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
22   0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
23   0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
24   0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
25   0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
26   0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited


[INPUT CHAIN]
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 REJECT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request reject-with icmp-port-unre
achable
2        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
3        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
4        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
5        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
6      330 18782 ACCEPT     udp  --  crc    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
7        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  crc    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
8       26  8430 ACCEPT     udp  --  crc    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
9        0     0 REJECT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request reject-with icmp-port-unre
achable
10       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  crc    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
11    737K  232M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
12    357K   26M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
13    1400  168K INPUT_direct  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
14    1400  168K INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
15    1400  168K INPUT_ZONES  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
16   0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
17    1395  168K REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

From my best understanding, my ping to 192.168.130.0/24 should be blocked entirely.
For 192.168.130.1 (crc interface), the packet should end up in the INPUT chain because kernel will treat the traffic as its own.
For 192.168.130.11 (an OCP router), the packet should be picked up by the FORWARD chain.

However, the result is out of my expectation. While the traffic for 192.168.130.1 was handled properly by INPUT chain, the traffic for 192.168.130.11 does not seem to be picked up by INPUT and FORWARD chains.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.130.11
PING 192.168.130.11 (192.168.130.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.130.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.218 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.130.11: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.227 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.130.11: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.183 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.130.11: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.971 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.130.11: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.180 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.130.11: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.171 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.130.11: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.238 ms
...

[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.130.1
PING 192.168.130.1 (192.168.130.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.130.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.130.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.130.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.130.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.130.1 icmp_seq=5 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.130.1 icmp_seq=6 Destination Port Unreachable
```

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You blocked ICMP for INPUT (incoming traffic) FORWARD (forwarded, ie routed traffic) but didn't block ICMP for OUTPUT (locally generated *outgoing* traffic). So your ICMP echo-request is not blocked to leave the system. The answer (echo-reply) has no rule blocking it either: ping works.

To block the ping *locally issued* you should also add this rule:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j REJECT
```

To test the FORWARD rule, the ping must be done from an other, routed, host.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helps me to better understanding networking! One more question, if you don't mind, I need the host machine (where the VM is running) to be able to connect to the "crc" bridge. Both the host and VM are on the same network. Is there a quick way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand well your question. The host *provides* the bridge named crc. Can you explain further?

Comment: The data provided in the original post was taken from a VMWare. It is where the "virbr0" and "crc" reside. What I wish to do now is the have the host machine (where the VMWare is running) to connect to the "crc" interface, so that it can interact with the resources (basically Openshift) running there.

Eg. "crc" = 192.168.130.1 and Openshift router = 192.168.130.11

Comment: rewrote completely my answer (since it was accepted I couldn't delete it, so I put the correct answer instead...)

Comment: for the vmware part, I don't know enough to help. YOu should ask a separate question